# Can't uninstall Riot vanguard

Tags: windows, filesystems, uninstall

When I go to control panel>programs>programs and features, Riot Vanguard is there. When I click to uninstall it asks if I want to allow windows to change things on this device. When I click yes programs and features says "an error occurred while trying to uninstall Riot Vanguard. It may have already been uninstalled. Would you like to remove Riot Vanguard from the programs and features list?" I click no.
When I go to files under this pc> local disk> Riot Games > Riot client everything appears to be here including services, system, resources (file folder), etc. Why can't I uninstall?
(Sorry this is an update when I tried to reinstall and then uninstall again as suggested by Ramhound) I also can find it under this pc> Local disk> Program files> Riot Vanguard. Though this one only has a file called logs with a text doc and a system file called vgk.

Comment: If you have System Restore enabled, revert to the point before you've started deleting stuff and then uninstall properly.

Comment: The simplest solution is to reinstall the software and that will restore the uninstaller, however, it's unclear "what files" you can't removed because you should be able to simply just delete the files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.